# How to block a specific URL in google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a chrome extension which blocks a specific URL like gmail.com and when someone goes to gmail.com they got pop up to enter the password to continue to that website, this may decrease unauthorized way of accessing your personal sites.

If you know something about let me know, I have googled some extension and there are two-three extensions which block sites like stay focused.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to inject a content script to all pages that should be 'protected' (you can set it up using "content_scripts"/"matches" setting in `manifest.json`). When script is injected and fired it should display the login dialog and handle the sign in process. You may use [this code](https://github.com/shreyansb/stay-focused/blob/master/manifest.json) as a starting point for your extension.

BTW, I don't think that your extension can really protect anything working the way you described it. Extensions may be easily deactivated/uninstalled.

Comment: looks easy, i think it will work. have to study little about manifest.json anyways thanks for the reply. and yea i didn't think in that extension can be easily deactivated. silly me :P

Comment: The way that you prevent it from being disabled is you add chrome://extensions/ to your blocklist.